# Where do I place this variable so both statements accept it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
$scope.deleteString = function() {
      myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if($scope.cursorPosVal > 0){
            $scope.name = [$scope.name.slice(0, $scope.cursorPosVal - 1) + $scope.name.slice($scope.cursorPosVal)].join('');
            console.log($scope.name);
            setTimeout(function(){ setCaretPosition("inputBox", $scope.cursorPosVal); }, 30);
        } else {
            $scope.cursorPosVal = 1;
        }
      }, 500);
    };
    $scope.stopInterval= function(){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    };
```

So here is a backspace button that I made in angular. It uses the text cursor to backspace from a point, not just deleting from the end of a string. I need to make an interval that essentially repeats the delete function if the user holds down the backspace button. I am trying to make it so that in the backspace div it looks something like the following,

```
<div id="backspace" ng-mousedown="deleteString(); decrementCursor();" ng-mouseup="stopInterval();">
```

I am using html, css, javascript/angular only. No jQuery. I have been struggling with this for a bit so if you took time to help me, I would be forever thankful.

Comment: right now, it currently deletes really wonky. It backspacing once, i.e. "enter tex" and then "staying." In my console, i have it print everytime the interval runs, it shows "enter text", "enter tex", "enter tex", etc.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make a working example of the problem you'd like to solve.